# 530 Error authenticating with ftplib

Tags: python, ftp, ftplib

Hello there everyone!

I am trying to write a script to automate various mundane tasks involved with my FTP server.

I was planning on using ftplib to connect and interface with the FTP server, but I am having some issues connecting to the server as my usual user.

here is the code I am using, password changed for obvious reasons:

```
from ftplib import FTP
ftp = FTP('ftp.centizen.ca','21') 
ftp.login('centizen@centizen.ca','password')
ftp.retrlines('LIST')
```

I get an error 530 from this. Any ideas on why?

I am certain that my credentials, including the password, are spelled correctly as they work when directly copied and pasted into filezilla. Is there something I am missing here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In

```
ftp = FTP('ftp.centizen.ca','21')
```

the '21' is taken as being the userid. Leave it out.

If you want to use a port different from 21, for example 2121, you need to

```
ftp=FTP()
ftp.connect('ftp.centizen.ca', 2121)
```

Comment: Hi Uselpa, thanks for your reply! It's great help. Can connect and run commands like normal now.